# I have been beginning

Tags: american-english

Verb begin something that happens in a moment, not something continuously. After that does this correct:

I have been beginning to learn English since 2000, but never continuous consistently, tenacious till now.

Comment: Are you learning English? Consider if your question suits our [ell.se] site better. :)

Answer (score 1):

**'Beginning' is not always something that happens in a moment.** It can also be ongoing.

People say things like:

> I am just beginning my analysis of the data

if they are five minutes into a day-long analysis.

A movie plot famously should have a beginning, a middle and an end. A movie that is still in the first part can be said to be 'beginning'.

**However**

No native English speaker would say "I have been beginning to learn English since 2000." Try

> I began learning English in 2000

or

> I have been learning English since 2000

Comment: No problem when "I began to learn English in 2000". But what if "I began to learn English from 2000 till now more times without success".

Comment: How about something like "I've been trying to learn English since 2000, but only recently started making real progress."

Comment: #user888379 it is ok, but my question is does this my sentence correct, I'm not native speaker:

I have been beginning to learn English since 2000, but never continuous consistently, tenacious till now.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker I would say, "I learned some English in 2000, but for the past two years have been studying it more seriously."

Comment: ""I learned some English in 2000" implies that you did not learn English in 2001-2017